# Как вывести часть данных из таблицы с отношение OneToMany?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Приветствую! Просьба помочь, есть две таблицы, в одной есть отношение по полю "id_new" к другой OneToMany. 
К примеру есть запрос на сервер типа: htttp://myserver/get/new/{token} 
Так вот, мне нужно сделать так чтобы в array list LikeOrDizlike попадали только те записи записи которым соответствует токен?
Не совсем понимаю как это сделать. 
Код первой сущности:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "news")
    public class News {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date newsDate;

        @Column(name = "summary", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String summary;

        @Column(name = "image_url", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String image_url;

        @Column(name = "category", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String category;

        @Column(name = "likeInt")
        private Long likeInt;

        @Column(name = "diz_likeInt")
        private Long diz_likeInt;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_news")
        private List<LikeOrDizlike> likeOrDizlike = new ArrayList<>(); 
+ геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

код второй сущности:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "LikeOrDizlike")
    public class LikeOrDizlike {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "id_news")
        private Long id_news;

        @Column(name = "token", nullable = false, length = 50)
        private String token;

        @Column(name = "onClickLike")
        private Boolean onClickLike;

        @Column(name = "onClickDizLike")
        private Boolean onClickDizLike;
+ геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

В проекте используется Spring-nibernate-JPA

Кастомные запрос описываю в интерфейсе унаследованном от JpaRepository.

Для наглядности, пример запроса: 
htttp://myserver/get/new/123456 и мне нужно чтобы были выведены только те записи у которых такой же токен(отметил желтым), а все остальное не нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это в контроллере:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "get/news/start/{id}token/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<News> getNewsID(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @PathVariable String token) {


        return service.findNewsStart(id);
    }
```

Код репы:

```
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News, Long>{
    //куча методов 

//возвращает новоые записи
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("select p from News p where p.id > :id_newsStart")
    List<News> findNewsToken(@Param("id_newsStart") long id_news);
}
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу участок кода, где вы делаете выборку из базы и выводите результат

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста)

Comment: По `News.id` тоже фильтр нужен, или только по `LikeOrDizlike.token`?

Comment: Да, нужен News.id и по LikeOrDizlike.token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
public interface NewsRepo extends JpaRepository<News, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "likeOrDizlike")
    List<News> findAllByLikeOrDizlike_Token(String token)

    // Или так:
    @Query("select n from News n join fetch n.likeOrDizlike l where l.token = ?1")
    List<News> getNewsByLikeOrDizlike_Token(String token)
}
```

[RTM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)

**UPDATE 1**

Боюсь, что первый вариант не заработает, т.к. `Like` и `Or` - зарезервированные слова. Не стоит сущностям давать подобные наименования.

Если переименуешь вторую сущность, например, в `Feedback` (а соотв. ей поле в сущности `News` в `feedbacks`, то метод будет выглядеть так:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "feedbacks")
List<News> findAllByFeedbacks_Token(String token)
```

**UPDATE 2**

> Да, нужен News.id и по LikeOrDizlike.token

Тогда метод должен возвращать не список а одну запись:

```
@Query("select n from News n join fetch n.likeOrDizlike l where n.id = ?1 and l.token = ?1")
Optional<News> getNewsByIdAndLikeOrDizlike_Token(Long id, String token)

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "feedbacks")
Optional<News> findByIdAndFeedbacks_Token(Long id, String token)
```

**UPDATE 3**

Что касается `Specification` я бы подправил так:

```
private Specification<News> findByIdAndFeedbacks_Token(Long id, String token) {
    return (news, query, cb) -> {
        return cb.and(
                cb.equal(news.get("id"), id)
                cb.equal(news.join("likeOrDizlike").get("token"), token)
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: А как мне соединить запрос в один по типу: @Query("select n from News n where n.id > 1 and join fetch n.likeOrDizlike l where l.token = :token ")
    List<News> getNewsByLikeOrDizlike_Token(@Param("token") String token); Ну то есть выполнить условие where n.id > 1, а потом остальное. У меня выдает ошибку.

Comment: @Android-EE см. обновленный ответ. (Настоятельно рекомендую поменять название сущностей...)

Comment: Не могли бы вы глянуть мой второй вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712379/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-onetomany

Answer (score 3):

Используйте JpaSpecification. Интерфейс должен расширять `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>`, в вашем случае так:

```
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<News> { ... }
```

Спецификация для фильтрации:

```
/**
 * Спецификация для фильтра по токену
 */
private Specification<News> createSpecification(Long id, String token) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Predicate tokenPredicate = cb.equal(root.join("likeOrDizlike").get("token"), token);
        return cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id), tokenPredicate);
    };
}
```

Получение списка новостей по токену:

```
newsRepository.findAll(createSpecification(1, "123456"));
```

Comment: Вылетает ошибка:Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [likeOrDizlike.token] on this ManagedType [com.reweu.server.entity.News]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [likeOrDizlike.token] on this ManagedType [com.reweu.server.entity.News]

Comment: внес изменения в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Я бы подгружал List likeOrDizlike по необходимости из репозитория с помощью кастомного запроса

```
@Query("<you_query in :token>")
List<LikeOrDizlike> findByToken(@Param("token") Iterable<String> tokens);
```

Либо нужно менять структуру базы, добавлять промежуточную сущность.