# Как правильно сделать фильтр с отношением OneToMany?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Ранее задавал вопрос здесь: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711447/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-onetomany)

Все работает, но теперь мне нужно сделать еще более странную вещь.

У меня есть две таблицы, в одной есть отношение по полю "id_news" к другой OneToMany. Мне нужно сделать фильтр так чтобы при запросе выводились все данные из первой таблицы списком и если есть записи во второй таблице с тем же id_news что и в первой но при этом токен в запросе не соответствует токену в этой записи то запись должны выводиться все равно, пример:

запрос - вывести все записи с id больше 0 и токеном 123 
 - /get/news/start/0/token/123

Сейчас есть фильтр по id и токену, так он реализован:

```
  @Query("select p from News p join fetch p.feedback l where p.id > :id_news and l.token = :token")
        List<News> findNewsToken(@Param("id_news") long id_news, @Param("token") String token);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно чтобы было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть данные из первой таблицы вывелись, а данные со второй таблице нет, т.к в столбце токен другой и равен 5698.

Код первой сущности:
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "news")
    public class News {

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 10000)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date newsDate;

    @Column(name = "summary", nullable = false, length = 10000)
    private String summary;

    @Column(name = "image_url", nullable = false, length = 10000)
    private String image_url;

    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false, length = 10000)
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "likeInt")
    private Long likeInt;

    @Column(name = "diz_likeInt")
    private Long diz_likeInt;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_news")
    private List<Feedback> feedback = new ArrayList<>();
+ геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Код второй сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Feedback")
public class Feedback {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "id_news")
    private Long id_news;

    @Column(name = "token", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String token;

    @Column(name = "onClickLike")
    private Boolean onClickLike;

    @Column(name = "onClickDizLike")
    private Boolean onClickDizLike;
+ геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

В проекте используется Spring-nibernate-JPA
Думал что можно это сделать как-то через ленивую инициализацию, но пока решение не нашел, подскажите как мне быть или в какую сторону копать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй `...left join fetch...`

Comment: Нет, это видимо так не работает.

Comment: "select n from News n left join fetch n.feedback l where n.id > 0 and l.token = :token" - все то же самое

Comment: )) это потому, что у тебя стоит второе условие, на токен, записи, где нет токен в выборку не попадают

Comment: да, я это понимаю, вот мне и надо сделать так чтобы записи попадали, а если нет ему соответствия токену во второй таблице то пустота как на скрине выше. Это возможно сделать?

Comment: Ну так ты должен определиться с условием. Или ты хочешь, чтобы в выборку попали записи с определённым токеном или что-то другое..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64895/discussion-between-android-ee-and-cepr0).

Comment: Не могу, я в дороге  (

Comment: Я может просто чего то не понимаю. Я в запросе передаю id и токен.
Мне нужно сделать так чтобы выводились записи с первой таблицы с id больше переданного в запросе
и мне не нужно тянуть все соответствия со второй таблицы,
а только те записи у которых токен который я передаю в запросе. Как в последнем скрине у id - 2 есть соответствия во второй таблице, но там токен другой и поэтому пустота.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению JPQL не поддерживает left join с условием. Поэтому в лоб эту задачу похоже решить нельзя. Можно пойти на хитрость. Все равно тебе нужно выбрать все записи "слева", поэтому убираем из запроса второе условие, а потом в полученной коллекции удаляем лишние фидбеки, т.е. те, которые не содержат нужный токен:

```
@Query("select distinct n from News n join fetch n.feedback f where n.id > ?1")
List<News> findNewsByIdGreaterThen(long id);

default List<News> findNewsByIdGreaterThenAndToken(long id, String token) {
    List<News> news = findNewsByIdGreaterThen(long id);
    for (News n : news) {
        // Удаляем лишние фидбеки...
    }    
    return news;  
}
```

Comment: Сделал все как ты сказал, я получил то что хотел, за исключением одного, теперь происходит задвоение записей, к примеру -скрин приложил в самый конец, почему id = 2 - две записи, а должна быть одна.

Comment: И количество этих дубликатов равно количеству записей во второй таблице с тем же id то есть 2.

Comment: @Android-EE добавил distinct в селект, проверь, плз, что выйдет выйдет...

Comment: Да, это работает. Спасибо

Comment: @Android-EE Отлично! )